# ramonak/react-progress-bar animate the stripes right to left

Tags: css, reactjs, progress-bar

I am using ramonak/react-progress-bar. My current progressbar looks like this -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5gqU.png)
I want an animated stripes like this progressbar -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODLds.png)

```
<ProgressBar
  completed={completed}
  isLabelVisible={false}
  bgColor="#507B1C"
  baseBgColor="rgba(56, 85, 60, 0.20)"
  height="24px"
/>
```

I tried using custom css but not working. I want an animated stripes right to left/ left ot right.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.